# Is it possible to send XHR to from one domain to another domain

Tags: javascript, security, http, post, https

Is it possible to make a POST request to other domain (say xyz.com) from for e.g. abc.com?, Please consider the following scenario

1. We have a Login Page on our web application, after login it connects to server.
2. If someone other than me knows the request/data format for the login request.
3. Can he create his own web application to connect to a server using my Request format?

My concern here is not the legal issues, but if this is technically possible or not?

PS : We can get the request headers and data payload of any XHR from "Developer Tools" of browser

Thanks,

Rohit

Comment: "*Suppose if any great web developer want to develop his own web application to connect "XYZ " server. is he able to do that?*" It depends. "*if not what are the factors which will stop him to do that. what more information one need to know to do this?*" Lack of an organized API, Terms and Conditions policies prohibiting it, and a billion other things. This question is **way** too broad for the format of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is known as a [CSRF attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).

Another domain can POST to yours, but not read the response due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).